# Mssql query returns ? in place of accented characters

Tags: php, sql-server

right I'm running a mssql stored procedure in PHP and the accented characters appear to be returned as ?
The stored procedure is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dbname]
@ProjectID AS int
AS
SELECT ProjectName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS ProjectName, 
CustomerName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS CustomerName
FROM Project
WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectID
END
```

My PHP relating to this is (the return values shown are for ABCDĒčďāĀÖØÖÖÃēù)

```
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
    or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
    or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
$stmt=mssql_init("select.Project", $dbhandle);
$desktopid = $_GET['desktopid'];
$compid = 0;
$custid = 0;
mssql_bind($stmt, "@ProjectID", $desktopid, SQLINT4, FALSE, FALSE);
$result = mssql_execute($stmt);
$row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['ProjectName'];          ==== ABCD????????????
utf8_decode($row['ProjectName']);  ==== ABCD????????????
utf8_encode($row['ProjectName']);  ==== ABCD????????????
```

I could do with a hand figuring out how to decode the characters that the function returns I've found no help from other sources online and I've even tried several fixes from stack overflow to no avail.

Please also note that if I had the choice I would be using mysql with php not mssql and that I have php running on a debian server

Comment: What encoding is the database set to? UTF-8?

Comment: The collation of the database is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS however as for encoding I have no idea how to find that out

Comment: The question marks in SQL Server usually means that one is trying to store unicode strings in a varchar column. If you are using varchar for columns ComputerName and ProjectName you could try to change those to nvarchar instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this database doesn't belong to us, it belongs to our client  we're allowed to update stored procedures, read and write data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to call `ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');` (or change that setting in the php.ini file).

Thank you to Mikael Eriksson for giving me the search term I was missing (unicode) to help me find the answer on http://agimpert.blogspot.com/2011/01/unicode-php-headaches.html